# How to export and import js script?

Tags: vue.js

Hello I have a code like this which works fine in main.js

```js
Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution = 
  document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 && document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
    ? 1080
    : 2160;
```

However, I have a lot of similar things and I would like to move the prototype code into another file.
For example, I tried to do it like this

```js
//main.js
import "./vue-extensions/prototypes"

//prototypes.js
import Vue from "vue"

export {
  Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
    document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
    document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
      ? 1080
      : 2160
}
```

But I have an error Unexpected token, expected "," in Vue.prototype

Comment: You don't appear to be importing Vue.

Comment: if I add import Vue from "vue";, for example 
import Vue from "vue";
export {
 Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
 document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
  document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
  ? 1080
  : 2160;
} I will get  
Syntax Error: D:\Projects\FrontEnd\gta\src\vue-extensions\prototypes.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:4)

> 5 |   Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
    |      ^
  6 |   document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
  7 |           document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
  8 |           ? 1080

Comment: I don't think you need to export anything. Just move the `Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution=...` after import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax looks incorrect.

The external file does not need to export anything. It should just include the `Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution` assignment:

```js
// prototypes.js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
    document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
        document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
        ? 1080
        : 2160;
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/side-effects-library-dlh0o?file=/src/prototypes.js)

You could also make this a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) by exporting a function that receives the `Vue` to modify:

```js
// prototypes.js
export default Vue => {
  Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
    document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
        document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080
        ? 1080
        : 2160;
}
```

...which would be used like this:

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyPlugin from './prototypes'

Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-a-vue-plugin-rwgmc?file=/src/prototypes.js)